# Unsubscribe from event after it fires

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, event-handling

We have an object which is not getting disposed by the garbage collector and we believe it's because of a rouge event registered to the object reconstructed later on that is never un-registered.

We have created a method that runs when a form is being returned too. (Say for example we go from Form A to B, then back to A. The method will run on the *back to A*). In that method we are checking if we are coming back from Form B. If we are then create an instance of that form and attach an event on the `.FormClosed`.

This code was pulled from one of our partners so I don't know the reason why they decided to attach the `.FormClosed` event when the context of the event it's attached in is *supposed* to be when it's closed already. (Hence the *back to A*).

What I don't know is, how do I detach from the `.FormClosed` event, but still keep the logic that's fired there?

The basis of the code is:

```
private void Returning(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CoreForm frmSomeChildForm = sender as CoreForm

    if (frmSomeChildForm.Name == "frmB") // We are 'returning' from B
    {
        // Do stuff
        frmSomeChildForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(SomeMethod);
    }
}

private void SomeMethod(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // This was in the comments for the method:
    // Event added to re-position the search panel back to the top by removing
    //the other two panels and adding them back to the form.
    // The code just calls parent methods of DLLs we don't have the source for.
}
```

Since the `Returning` method is basically called when we are returning from Form B, does it make any sense why we are attaching the `.FormClosed` event there? Can't I do something like this?

```
private void Returning(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CoreForm frmSomeChildForm = sender as CoreForm

    if (frmSomeChildForm.Name == "frmB") // We are 'returning' from B
    {
        // Do stuff

        SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

So `Returning` is fired on the form we are returning from's `FormClosed()` event.  So the form we are returning from should already be closed.

The purpose of `SomeMethod` is not entirely clear, but it seems like it has to do with resetting the display of a couple of controls.

Comment: Nobody here really knows (A) to what event `Returning` is subscribed to (and, if this is a custom event, under which exact conditions this unknown event will be raised exactly when) and (B) what `SomeMethod` actually does (which could give insight of whether there is a reason it was made an event handler for FormClosed). So, i guess we shrug our shoulders and say: Maybe you could do something like this, maybe not...

Comment: By the way, subscribing to the FormClosed event of a form that is sooner or later being garbage collected does not create a memory leak. Since the event holds references to its subscribers (and not the other way round), garbage-collecting the form would also make those references to the forms' event subscribers vanish...

Comment: @elgonzo Right, but Form A lives on longer then Form B. My understanding of it is that if Form A creates a reference to Form B, and that object subscribes to an event on Form A, then it will not be marked to be collected since Form A lives longer than Form B. So the object created is just waiting for Form A to Dispose until  it can Dispose.

Comment: If the `Returning` event is fired immediately prior to a call to `this.Close()` then you should be able to just do your call to `SomeMethod()` in `Returning`. If not they you may still require adding the event handler to `FormClosed()`.

Comment: I see. Well, i wish i could be more helpful, but as said in my 1st comment, there is not enough useful information in your question to give some meaningful advice :-( (There is a pretty good chance if you start explaining this to us in detail, you will realize a solution/fix by yourself. Kind of "[explain to a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)" approach)

Comment: *"So Returning is fired on the form we are returning from's FormClosed() event. So the form we are returning from should already be closed....I don't know the reason why they decided to attach the .FormClosed event when the context of the event it's attached in is supposed to be when it's closed already."* Then why not just remove it? What's wrong with the second option you proposed?